# Let {$b_k$} be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers that converges to b and suppose that b>0. Prove that {$\sqrt{b_k}$} converges to $\sqrt{b}$.

Tags: analysis

So far for my proof I have:

Let {$b_k$} be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers that converges to b and suppose that b>0.
Then, given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a N $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq N$ $\Rightarrow$ $|b_k-b|< \epsilon$. Now, consider {$\sqrt{b_k}$}. We need to show that {$\sqrt{b_k}$} $\rightarrow \sqrt{b}$.
Then, $|(\sqrt{b_k})^2-(\sqrt{b})^2| < \epsilon$ for all $k \geq N$.

After this point I am stuck. I not sure how to manipulate the expression so that I can arrive at getting some form of $\epsilon < k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\sqrt{b_k}-\sqrt{b}|=|\frac{b_k-b}{\sqrt{b_k}+\sqrt{b}}|\leq\frac{|b_k-b|}{\sqrt{b}}$$

> Explanation

For the equality, I used the formula $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2$,
and that for positive numbers $a>0$ we have $(\sqrt{a})^2=a$.
For the inequality, I used the fact that $\sqrt{b_k}+\sqrt{b}\geq \sqrt{b}$ (can you see why this inequality is true?) and also the fact that if $a,b,c$ are positive numbers such that $b\geq c$ then $\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{a}{c}$.

Comment: I don't understand how arrived at that inequality